# how add javascript code in codeigniter controller inside __construct(){ }

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

i want to add  in codeigniter controller __construct()  to store user data in localStorage,

this is my below code

```
<?php
class Dashboard extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct() {
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        localStorage.setItem('ruuser_id', '<?php echo $_SESSION['ruuser_id'];?>');
        localStorage.setItem('rufname', '<?php echo $_SESSION['rufname'];?>');
        localStorage.setItem('rulname', '<?php echo $_SESSION['rulname'];?>');
        localStorage.setItem('bru_staff', '<?php echo $_SESSION['bru_staff'];?>');
        localStorage.setItem('ruuser_emailid', '<?php echo $_SESSION['ruuser_emailid'];?>');
        localStorage.setItem('ruseller_id', '<?php echo $_SESSION['ruseller_id'];?>');
    </script>
    <?php
    parent::__construct();
}
```

When i am adding script code i am getting below error:

```
Severity: Warning

Message: session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /home/deveventadviser/public_html/development/application/controllers/Dashboard.php:7)

Filename: Session/Session.php
```

Can you suggest how to add  in __construct function

Comment: In controllers you cant set like that. you must load the view and try to add JavaScript in footer

Comment: my above code is working on localhost , but its not working in server

Comment: you should load session in controllers or autoload then only you can call sessions. please go through this link=> https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html

Comment: what ever you have written way is not at all correct way... you should write javascript code in views only...

Comment: Session is already loaded in autoload

Comment: Used javascript library instead.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a correct way to use javascript code in php class file but solution is that. You should define a property variable and use it like that.

```
<?php 

class Dashboard extends CI_Controller

{
 public $this->jScript = ''; 
public function __construct() 

{

    parent::__construct();

    // set property value 

    $this->jScript = "<script type='text/javascript'> //your stuff here </script>";



}

public function abc() {

$data['jScript'] = $this->jScript;

$this->load->view('abc',$data);

} 

}
```